# How to merge two 16 bit dW in one DD number in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, fibonacci, emu8086, bigint, extended-precision

with the following code I calculate first 30 elements of fibonacci sequence. **Note that every two element of arr represent one element of the fibonacci sequence while the fibonnaci numbers after 26th element will need more than 2 byte to represent.**

```
StSeg   Segment STACK 'Stack'
        DB 100H DUP (?)
StSeg   Ends

DtSeg   Segment
        arr   dw 62 dup (?)
        the30 dd ?
DtSeg   Ends

CDSeg   Segment
        ASSUME CS:CDSeg, DS:DtSeg, SS:StSeg
Start:
        MOV AX, DtSeg ; set DS to point to the data segment
        MOV DS,AX
        
        ; PROBLEM: STORE FIRST TWENTY ELEMENTS OF FIBONACCI IN AN ARRAY FROM MEMORY.
        ; SOLUTION:
        mov bx, offset arr
        add bx, 2
        mov [bx], 00H
        add bx, 4
        mov [bx], 01H
        ; inited fibo[0] = 00000000H and fibo[1] = 00000001H    
        mov cx, 29; make while loop counts 29 times.
        while:   
        
        ;first part addition
        mov ax, [bx]
        mov dx, [bx-4] 
        add ax, dx
        mov dx, 00H
        jnc else
        mov dx, 01H          
        
        ; second part addition
        else:
        mov [bx+4], ax
        mov ax, [bx-2]
        add dx, [bx-6]
        add ax, dx
        mov [bx+2], ax
        add bx, 4
        loop while
        
        
        MOV AH, 4CH
        MOV AL, 0
        INT 21H
CDSeg   ENDS
END Start
```

my college assignment asks to store the 30th element in variable named *the30* which **DD** but I do not know how is that even possible when all of the registers are 16 bits at most.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Look up "multiple precision arithmetic" and the ADC instruction.

Comment: But storing is easy: just store the low 16 bits at address `the30` and the high 16 bits at address `the30+2`.